# Prevent Yii from loading JS out of assets

Tags: yii

Is there a way to configure Yii such that it will no longer load *any* Javascript out of the Assets folder?

Comment: I guess no. This is strange desire... What problem are you trying to resolve?

Comment: To be honest, I don't like Yii.  I'm working on transitioning this project away from it.  As part of that process I want to load *MY* JS libraries, not what comes with Yii because I'm seeing so many dependency issues.

Comment: You can disable Yii-jquery and other script from config. something like that:

Comment: 'clientScript' =>array('scriptMap'=> array(
                'jquery.js'=>false,
                'jquery.ba-bbq.js'=>false,
                'jquery.yiilistview.js'=>false
            ));

Comment: The problem with that is that it appears to still try to load some strange generated files.  For example '/assets/6c498e87/482f9b499cd1484e22eb51112fc0eee4.js' which is just a CKEditor config (despite my not actually having it set to load CKEditor). But if I do want to load CKEditor then that file is going to break things!  So ideally I would be able to tell Yii not to load any Javascript from assets whatsoever.

Comment: How do you include CKEditor in your app, is it an extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your own AssetManager or extend current

protected/components/DummyAssetManager.php:

```
class DummyAssetManager extends CApplicationComponent {
    public function publish(){}
}
```

add into `components` array in
protected/config/main.php:

```
    'assetManager'=>array(
        'class'=>'DummyAssetManager',
    ),
```

Comment: could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager) for a detailed description of
the assetManager options

I think you can try following option in your config/main.php

```
'components' => array(
   'assetManager' => array(
     'linkAssets' => true,
   ),
),
```

This will make asset files symbolic links to your original js/css sources. See [linkAssets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAssetManager#linkAssets-detail) for more details on it.

If your PHP<5.3, or the OS it's running on doesn't support symbolic links, you won't be able to use 'linkAssets' option, in this case you can try:

```
'components' => array(
   'assetManager' => array(
     'forceCopy' => true,
   ),
),
```

This should update asset folder on every request. These two options are usually used during development process (btw, you can't use both) and should be removed from production.

PS: if you're sure that you haven't explicitly enabled ckeditor somewhere in your code and you're confident about your assetmanager calls throughout the code, check your layout and page for widgets that require this CKeditor, as Yii can't preload 'stuff' just randomly, it can be triggered by some preloaded component/extension or yii widget.